# What is the best armor/weapons to use on The Twins

Tags: terraria

I have tried Palladium armor and Orichalicum armor and a few high damage weapons. I am having trouble with the cursed fire guy(Spazmatism) i have no trouble with the other guy.

I need to deafeat him to advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are vast resources available already, so i won't go into detail here but just leave the link for you: https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:The_Twins_strategies